# Python click module not working with hyphenized argument

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I tried to pass multiple arguments to my python script (`opsgit`) using the `click` module like this:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument('arguments', nargs=-1)
def cli(arguments):
    """CLI for git"""
    cmd = create_command(arguments)
    _execute_command(cmd)
```

When I execute this command line:

```
$ opsgit git checkout -b pvt_test
```

I get this error:

```
Usage: opsgit git [OPTIONS] [ARGUMENTS]...
Try "opsgit git --help" for help.
    
Error: no such option: -b
```

Can anyone let me know how to solve this one?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `ignore_unkown_options` flag. Here is your example with the flag added. Check out the [docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/advanced/?highlight=nargs) for more info on how to use `nargs`.

```
import click

@click.command(context_settings=dict(
    ignore_unknown_options=True,
))
@click.argument('arguments', nargs=-1)
def cli(arguments):
    """CLI for git"""
    cmd = click.create_command(arguments)
    _execute_command(cmd)
```